# How to install Drools plugin in Eclipse Indigo IDE

Tags: drools

How to install the drools plugin in eclipse and how to use it.Anyone has an idea.

Comment: Step by Step by procedure to set up drools plugin in eclipse IDE had been provided in the following link. Here detailed explanation with screenshots are provided [**Procedure to install DROOLS plugin in Eclipse**](http://a4academics.com/tutorials/58-drools-tutorial-and-example/495-procedure-to-install-drools-plugin-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 83):

I don't know much about how to use it, but to install it as an eclipse plugin, this should work:

1. Start Eclipse
2. Help -> Install New Software
3. In the Work With: or Site: input field, enter: "**[http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/`](http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/%60)<VERSION`>.Final/org.drools.updatesite/**", replace "``" with appropriate version and click the "Add" button
4. For the **Name** you can just enter "Drools"
5. Check the Drools and jBPM checkbox and follow the instructions to get it installed.

Master the Boss http://www.mastertheboss.com/ has some tutorials on how to use it as well

The Drools downloads page is at: http://www.jboss.org/drools/downloads

Comment: Mid 2014, I used "Help / Install New Software" and wired up this URL.  http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.Final/org.drools.updatesite/

Comment: The update site URL given in this answer is subject to change. The given URL is specific to the 5.5.0.Final release of Drools. It's better to go to the drools download page, http://www.drools.org/download/download.html, then look (currently towards the bottom of the page) for the Eclipse Update Site section, then use that URL in step 3 of this answer.

Comment: **September 2015**,  I used "Help / Install New Software" and wired up this URL http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.Final/org.drools.updatesite/

Comment: This answer should include the explanation given by Erick G. Hagstrom.