# Why JBOSS drools plugin is not working in Helios?

Tags: eclipse, drools, helios

I have installed drools plugin in Helios for linux machine.After installing a prompt displayed as,

```
An error has occurred.see error log for more details,
org/eclipse/ui/part/FileEditorInput
```

I have referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273309/how-to-install-drools-plugin-in-eclipse-indigo-ide) for installation.

Drools plugin is not working in helios?

How to solve this?

Comment: I couldn't make any sense of the drools download page, but in general, Eclipse plug-ins are written for a specific version of Eclipse.  They may work on newer versions.  They **never** work on earlier versions.  Try installing on Indigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you did, but I just downloaded Eclipse Helios 3.6 RC4, Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, and then installed from the update site at:
http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/org.drools.updatesite/

After restarting Eclipse at the end of the installation, I could open the Drools and jBPM perspectives without any issues.

I'd also recommend to use a more recent version of Eclipse though.

Kris

Comment: You may wish to try the update site http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/org.drools.updatesite/ Currently it points to 5.5.0 Final but it may not in the future.